# How to debug a crashed memcached?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, memcached

I launched memcached using "/usr/bin/memcached -m 128 -p 11211 -U 
11211 > memcached.log 2>&1 &". I am running this on a ec2 ubuntu 11. 
It just crashed without any warning or log to the console or file.

Where do I start debugging this ?

Edit : I ran memcached with -vvv and got this towards the end of the log file. memcached hardly made about 10 requests and died.

```
> NOT FOUND -1002256595
>30 STORED
30: going from conn_nread to conn_write
30: going from conn_write to conn_new_cmd
30: going from conn_new_cmd to conn_waiting
30: going from conn_waiting to conn_read
30: going from conn_read to conn_parse_cmd
<30 set 160268806ProviderList 1 0 1372
30: going from conn_parse_cmd to conn_nread
> NOT FOUND 160268806ProviderList
>30 STORED
30: going from conn_nread to conn_write
30: going from conn_write to conn_new_cmd
30: going from conn_new_cmd to conn_waiting
30: going from conn_waiting to conn_read
30: going from conn_read to conn_parse_cmd
<30 set -1938194056UserDetails 1 0 356
30: going from conn_parse_cmd to conn_nread
> NOT FOUND -1938194056UserDetails
>30 STORED
30: going from conn_nread to conn_write
30: going from conn_write to conn_new_cmd
30: going from conn_new_cmd to conn_waiting
30: going from conn_waiting to conn_read
30: going from conn_read to conn_parse_cmd
<30 set 160268806UserDetails 1 0 364
30: going from conn_parse_cmd to conn_nread
> NOT FOUND 160268806UserDetails
>30 STORED
30: going from conn_nread to conn_write
30: going from conn_write to conn_new_cmd
30: going from conn_new_cmd to conn_waiting
30: going from conn_waiting to conn_read
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to run it as a daemon using -d option. Once I added it, crash's disappeared. Crazy I must say. @James thanks.

/usr/bin/memcached -m 128 -vvv -p 11211 -U 11211 -u ubuntu -d

Comment: Have you found crash cause? Was it a Heisenbug ?

Comment: yeah, if you dont load it with -d option it crashed

Answer (score 2):

usr/bin/**memcached-debug** -m 128 -p 11211 -U 11211 > memcached.log 2>&1 &

if you have it. If not you can build it from source. Also, try attaching an strace to the process (assuming this is repeatedly happening).

Comment: I am trying memcached -vvv. In parallel also trying what you suggested.

Comment: I could not find memcached-debug